# How to show that a limit diverges to $−∞$

Tags: real-analysis

How would you show that $\lim_{n→∞}\ln(1/n)=−∞$ using the definition of what it means to diverge to $−∞$. If I plug in different $n$ I see that it goes to $−∞$, but I don't understand how to show this. Could someone please demonstrate?

Comment: Are you allowed to do a substitution, that is $n=1/x$ and then use basic properties of the natural log as how  this logarithm is introduced? Also, you asked this question half hour ago....

Comment: It's not the _limit_ that diverges to $-\infty$; it is the _sequence_ that diverges to $-\infty.$ The _limit is_ $-\infty. \qquad$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\ln 1 & = 0 \\[10pt]
\ln \frac 1 e & = -1 \\[10pt]
\ln \frac 1 {e^2} & = -2 \\[10pt]
\ln \frac 1 {e^3} & = -3 \\[10pt]
\ln \frac 1 {e^4} & = -4 \\
& \, \vdots \\ & \, \vdots
\end{align}
As $n$ grows, it ultimately gets bigger than $e^4$, so that $\ln\dfrac 1 n < -4,$ and as it keeps growing, it gets bigger than $e^5$, so that $\ln\dfrac 1 n < -5$, and then it keeps growing until it's bigger than $e^6$, so that $\ln\dfrac 1 n < -6,$ and so on.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Let $A <0$ given.

we look for $N>0$ such that

$n>N \implies \ln (\frac {1}{n})<A $

or

$n>N \implies \ln (n)>-A $.

we can take $N=\lfloor e^{-A} \rfloor +2$.